# What does a non-dimensional change of variable means in $\frac{dT}{dt} = 6.35397 \times 10^{-9} \frac{T_F^4 - T^4}{355.205 + 0.200822 T} $?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following ODE:

$$\frac{dT}{dt} = 6.35397 \times 10^{-9} \frac{T_F^4 - T^4}{355.205 + 0.200822 T} $$

with the condition $T(0)=300$ and $T_F = 1200$.

A non-dimensional change of variable $\gamma = \frac{T}{T_F}$ is done resulting in:

$$\frac{d\gamma}{dt} = 10.980 \frac{1 - \gamma^4}{355.205 + 240.96\gamma}$$

I don't get the idea of what does a non-dimensional change of variable means. Neither how to do it. From where did they got to $10.980$? And, why would we want that kind of change in variables if we already have $T_F$? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Heuristics for the step size in numerical solvers, if by human intuition or programmed controllers (which are codified human intuition), work best if the problem is transformed close to a standard situation where all variables have scales or ranges of magnitudes close to 1. In that sense, the scale factor for $T$ could also have been $100$ or $1000$.

Another more theoretical goal in non-dimensionalization is to reduce the number of parameters. This makes it easier to compile a catalogue of qualitative properties of solutions of the given class of equations, for instance in a bifurcation analysis. In that direction one coefficient can be cancelled from the denominator, and the leading factor can be removed by rescaling the time axis, so that
$$
\frac{dγ}{d\tau}=\frac{1-γ^4}{1+cγ}
$$
only has one remaining parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm still too naïve both in maths and english to get the details you describe but I do get the idea of making things easier for solving with numerical methods. Is the 10.980 in my problem the remaining parameter? Or the original $6.35397 \times 10^{-9}$ also suffered a some kind of rescaling?

Comment: @JeniferÁvila They replace $T$ everywhere by $T_F\gamma$ and then "cancel" the $T_F^4$ in the numerator with the leading coefficient (and with the factor of $T_F$ that appears on the left hand side as well). Thus the 10.980 is the $6.35397 \cdot 10^{-9}$ times $T_F^3$.